# Android: Create a toggle button with image and no text

Tags: android, customization, togglebutton

is it possible to create a toggle button in Android that has an image but no text?
Ideally it would look like this:

[image: Toggle Button With Image]

Ive seen similar posts where the answer was to change the background but i want to preserve the Holo Light layout and just swap the text with an image.

I need to be able to programaticallly change the image source,

Any ideas how i would make this?

If this cant be done, is there a way i can make a normal button toggle on and off?

Comment: There is AFAIK no easy way to replace text with an image besides swapping the entire 2 state background image with the one you want. You could try if you can set the text to be the image via [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616437/imagespan-in-a-widget

Answer (score 123, accepted):

1. **Can I replace the toggle text with an image**

   No, we can not, although we can hide the text by overiding the default style of the toggle button, but still that won't give us a toggle button you want as we can't replace the text with an image.
2. **How can I make a normal toggle button**

   Create a file **ic_toggle** in your `res/drawable` folder

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:state_checked="false"
             android:drawable="@drawable/ic_slide_switch_off" />

       <item android:state_checked="true"
             android:drawable="@drawable/ic_slide_switch_on" />

   </selector>
   ```

   Here `@drawable/ic_slide_switch_on` & `@drawable/ic_slide_switch_off` are images you create.

   Then create another file in the same folder, name it **ic_toggle_bg**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:id="@+android:id/background"  
             android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

       <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle"
             android:drawable="@drawable/ic_toggle" />

   </layer-list>
   ```

   Now add to your custom theme, (if you do not have one create a styles.xml file in your `res/values/`folder)

   ```
   <style name="Widget.Button.Toggle" parent="android:Widget">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_toggle_bg</item>
      <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
   </style>

   <style name="toggleButton"  parent="@android:Theme.Black">
      <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/Widget.Button.Toggle</item>
      <item name="android:textOn"></item>
      <item name="android:textOff"></item>
   </style>
   ```

   This creates a custom toggle button for you.
3. **How to use it**

   Use the custom style and background in your view.

   ```
     <ToggleButton
           android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="right"
           style="@style/toggleButton"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg"/>
   ```

Comment: This is brilliant thanks. Is there anywhere that i can find the @drawable/ic_slide_switch_on and off images used for the Holo Light Toggle Buttons?

Comment: they are in `sdk\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable-hdpi` btn_toggle files, also you can see this android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Comment: Thanks so much! if I could up vote you more than once I would :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11499595/4896468  this only set `background`, seems simpler

Comment: I had to replace `@+android:id/toggle` with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663119/8981474) to have it work properly.  Otherwise it was the exact same solution I used.

Answer (score 66):

`ToggleButton` inherits from `TextView` so you can set drawables to be displayed at the 4 borders of the text. You can use that to display the icon you want on top of the text and hide the actual text

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textSize="0dp" />
```

The result compared to regular `ToggleButton` looks like

[image]

The seconds option is to use an [`ImageSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) to actually replace the text with an image. Looks slightly better since the icon is at the correct position but can't be done with layout xml directly.

You create a plain `ToggleButton`

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false" />
```

Then set the "text" programmatially

```
ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(this, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
SpannableString content = new SpannableString("X");
content.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
button.setText(content);
button.setTextOn(content);
button.setTextOff(content);
```

The result here in the middle - icon is placed slightly lower since it takes the place of the text.

[image]

Comment: Nice idea, i never saw the drawable options on togglebutton

Comment: @clairharrison If you have a `TextView` and an `ImageView` you often get this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318765/how-do-i-use-a-compound-drawable-instead-of-a-linearlayout-that-contains-an-imag - that's how I came up with that idea :)

Comment: ImageSpan worked great for me.  I actually wanted a `ToggleButton` that looked like a normal `Button` (without the blue bar) with different on/off images, so I refresh the ImageSpan on button click with a new image based off `isChecked()`.

Answer (score 62):

create toggle_selector.xml in res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

apply the selector to your toggle button

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/chkState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>
```

Note: for removing the text i used following in above code

```
textOff=""
textOn=""
```

Comment: I Guess that's the easy thing to do. It Worked, thanks!

Comment: Clean and simple! This answer should have more upvotes!

Comment: Does anyone know how to adjust its vertical position without using negative number on margin/padding?

Comment: I used this answer, exactly as it is presented, and get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290945/android-hide-stock-toggle-when-using-custom-background) error. The original toggle still displays on top of the background.

Comment: Indeed the cleanest and easiest to understand and reuse.

Comment: I was coming from an ImageView widget and couldn't get the image to show up. It took me sometime to realise the drawable attribute for a ToggleButton is "android:Background" and not "android:SRC"

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a little late, however for anyone interested, I've created a custom component that is basically a toggle image button, the drawable can have states as well as the background

https://gist.github.com/akshaydashrath/9662072