# WIFI type switch designing in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a scenario in my android app where I need to design a switch similar to the switch used to in WIFI,Bluetooth in Android device's setting screen. I am unable to change the background color of switch text. Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Janusz has explained styling of switches perfectly with details in the link below:

[How can I style an Android Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch)

Comment: So, is there no possibility where we can do it through programmatically  rather than this selector approach whcih is static.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching first before posting questions

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598255/android-create-a-toggle-button-with-image-and-no-text)

You can set the drawables inside the selector of your toggle button

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_slide_switch_off" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_slide_switch_on" />
</selector>
```