# Android, Hide stock toggle when using custom background?

Tags: android, xml, toggle, drawable, android-switch

I've got a custom drawable for my toggle switch

```
// toggle_selector.xlm
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Which I then apply to the switch

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/geoLocationsToggle"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:textSize="0dp" />
```

But the original (stock) toggle still shows overtop the custom background

[image: Toggle]

How do I get rid of the stock switch on top of my custom one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `android:thumb` and `android:track`, not `android:background`

And you should write a `selector` for each one of them.

Comment: Also worked to just set the thumb and track to transparent, and then continue using the BG image I previously made.