# Overlapping text over togglebutton in android

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

I have created a toggle button programmatically and using it but when it is running on device ,the status of toggle button is overlapping over the toggle button.like in the image [image]

the code for toggle is given below

```
  ToggleButton tb[];
            tb=new ToggleButton[len];
            tb[i]=new ToggleButton(this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tbparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (90, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tbparams.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
            tb[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgtoggle);
            tb[i].setId(i+1);
            tb[i].setTextOff(" ");
            tb[i].setTextOn(" ");
            tb[i].setTag(stringList.get(i));
            tb[i].setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            tb[i].setLayoutParams(tbparams);
            layout.addView(tb[i]);

    tb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(handleOnClick(
            tb[i], tb[i].getId(),tb[i].getTag(),stringList));
```

**bgtoggle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <!--<item android:drawable="@drawable/on" android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/off" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/off"></item>-->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onsw" android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/offsw" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/offsw"></item>


</selector>
```

please help

Comment: It seams you might not have used **Layout** correctly. I mean required padding,margin and gravity.

Comment: @MehrajMalik the on and off in toggle button is not created by me

Comment: @Vishal You've set on/off texts to empty. So ideally this shouldn't happen. Can u set random text like `setTextOff("blahOFF")` and `setTextOn("blahON")` and update on the change? Thanks!

Comment: @not_again_stackoverflow not working still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all, I corrected it by setting textcolor tranparent

```
color value= #00ffffff
```

Comment: Nice. Also, you could look at this link for closure on the actual problem -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/18599104/6527796

Answer (score 0):

If you add the toggle button in the layout then it will display as you expect it to be. But in your case, where you are creating it dynamically, you can add

tb[i].performClick();

just before you add it in your linear layout.